# Attach a user to an existing Parse role in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a **user signup** method that looks like this:

```
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {

                    // Link user to the 'User' role
                    ParseQuery<ParseRole> roleQuery = ParseRole.getQuery();
                    roleQuery.whereEqualTo("name", "User");
                    roleQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseRole>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseRole parseRole, ParseException e) {

                            if (e == null) {

                                //final ParseRole tempParseRl = parseRole;
                                ParseRelation<ParseUser> tempRel = parseRole.getUsers();
                                Log.i("ParseRole: ", parseRole.getName().toString());
                               parseRole.getUsers().add(user);


                                //TODO: 4. Delete reg key used for this user
                            }

                            // Error on Role ACL
                            else {

                                dMenuVerData.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    //1. Hide the progress bar
                    dataVerPBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    //2. Show okBtn & successTxt
                    okBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    userSuccessTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    dataVerTitle.setText("Congratulations!");


                    //ParseRelation<ParseUser> tempRel = new ParseRelation<ParseUser>();
                    //tempParseRl.put("users");

                } else {

                    // Dismiss dialog, show Parse error
                    dMenuVerData.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

On Parse I have two roles created on the data-browser.
[image]

After executing the line:

```
<role>.getUsers().add(user);
```

I'm expecting to be able to see the recently signed-up user under the "users , instead this table is empty:
[image]

What am I missing? Is the

```
<role>.getUsers().add(user);
```

working properly? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you temporarily comment out all role-code? Does the user then get saved?

Comment: @Moonwalkr, yes. The signup works fine. I have also tried to add the role-attachment before the signup and (as shown in the code above - after successful signup) both with the same unsuccessful result. <role>.getUsers().add(<user>); returns void making debugging hard.

Answer (score 0):

The solution resides in using `<role>.saveInBackground();` method after adding a new user to the ParseRelation, so after the signup succeeded I added:

```
...
parseRole.getUsers().add(user);
parseRole.saveInBackground();
...
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you are not saving the role after you changed the users relation 
what can i see that you added the user to (the local list you get from `parseRole.getUsers()` but you didn't saved it (to sync the changes with the remote version)